# SQL Error in INSERT INTO query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error

I am having this error and I can't seem to find the correct answer. I'm writing it in PHP but after debugging i tried to write it directly at phpMyAdmin. Here's my SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO users ( 'fName' , 'lName' , 'pCity' , 'cue' , 'email' , 'pass' , 'bDate' ) VALUES ('Me', 'You', 'Sofia', 'adf', '***', '***', '02/02/2010')
```

And here's the error I get:

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''fName' , 'lName' , 'pCity' , 'cue' , 'email' , 'pass' , 'bDate' ) VALUES ('Kali' at line 1
```

I get the same error when running the corresponding php script on a server. Any ideas where I go wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the single quotes in the column identifiers.

Either use "`" or don't use the quotes

```
INSERT INTO users ( fName , lName , pCity , cue , email , pass , bDate ) VALUES ('Me', 'You', 'Sofia', 'adf', '***', '***', '02/02/2010')
```

As tadman mentioned, backticks are only needed if the column identifier has a space or reserved words

Example

```
INSERT INTO users ( fName , `Last Name` , pCity , cue , email , pass , bDate ) VALUES ('Me', 'You', 'Sofia', 'adf', '***', '***', '02/02/2010')
```

Comment: Backticks are only required on column names that have spaces, special characters, or conflict with [reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html).

Comment: I would say that it is bad practice to use spaces, special characters or reserved keywords in the first place

Answer (score 6):

Do not wrap your column identifiers in single quotes. Use ticks:

```
 INSERT INTO users ( `fName` , `lName` , `pCity` , `cue` , `email` , `pass` , `bDate` ) 
 VALUES ('Me', 'You', 'Sofia', 'adf', '***', '***', '02/02/2010')
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrong quotes:

```
INSERT INTO users ( 'fName' , 'lName' , 'pCity' ,  etc...
                    ^-----^-- etc...
```

`'` quotes turn things into strings. You want [backticks](http://blog.readability.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/backtick.png)  `` ` ``   instead:

```
INSERT INTO users ( `fName` , `lName` , `pCity` , etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

Since no one mentioned it, I would avoid using column names that have spaces, special characters or reserved words. Column names requiring back ticks will eventually lead to hard to track down errors.

Answer (score 1):

When you're performing an INSERT INTO you do not need to use a Single Quote around the Column Names. If you're INSERTing INTO Columns that have spaces in the Column Name, then you use the backtick to surround the Column Name.

```
INSERT INTO users ( `First Name` , `Last Name` , pCity , etc ....
```